# Roll a die $2$ times. What's the probability that the rolled sum is at least $6$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Roll a die / cube $2$ times. What's the probability that the rolled
>   sum is at least $6$?

I'm not quite sure how this is solved. So we got $2$ cubes. In total we have $6^2=36$ different possibilities. But we want the reverse order too, so we need to multiply $36$ by $2$, we have $72$. This is the denominator of the fraction. Now we need to look for the enumerator; amount of sums which is at least $6$.

Now I would just write all possibilities (without reverse order) on a paper and then multiply by $2$. But this is very inefficient.. Is there a better way of doing this? And is my approach correct at all? :s

So I got $26 \cdot 2 = 52$

In the end we have $$\frac{52}{72}= \frac{13}{18}\approx  72,2 \text{%}$$

Result seems realistic for me at least.

Comment: Looks fine!  Not sure why you multiply everything by 2 though .. you just have 26 ways to get at least 6 out of 36 possibilities

Comment: Hey! I love your posts, by the way. As a side note, “$.$” is used universally as the decimal separator in the English-speaking world. This varies amongst neighbors (specially in countries where the main language is descended from Latin), but the comma is usually reserved for separating every three digits to the left of the decimal marker and is sometimes even used to separate every three digits to the right as well! At any rate, the BIPM (the bureau that organizes the SI) recommends this format for STEM publications: $$4321.1234$$ $$54\,321.123\,45$$ $$654\,321.123\,456$$ and so on…

Comment: Here's the link to the various translations of the [*SI Brochure*](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) (sorry, I could not find the German translation, though it does exist). Page 133 of the English text outlines the convention I summarized, and page 169 discusses variations of the convention. Again, it isn't *mandatory*, but German is closer to English than French. Also, commas might cause problems—in math, these are used to separate arguments of functions, elements in sets, coordinates in ordered pairs, etc.—that a period wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multiplication by $2$ is not correct.  The order of throws is already accounted for in the $6^2=36$.  You might then notice that there is one way to get a sum of $2$, two ways to get a sum of $3$, etc. for a total of $10$ ways to get a sum less than $6$.  The chance of getting at least six is then $1-\frac {10}{36}=\frac{13}{18}$

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the most efficient solution, but it will help you to understand what's going on.

Let's start by making a table of the possibilities:
\begin{array}{cccccc}
(1,1)& (1,2)& (1,3)& (1,4)& (1,5)& (1,6)\\
(2,1)& (2,2)& (2,3)& (2,4)& (2,5)& (2,6)\\
(3,1)& (3,2)& (3,3)& (3,4)& (3,5)& (3,6)\\
(4,1)& (4,2)& (4,3)& (4,4)& (4,5)& (4,6)\\
(5,1)& (5,2)& (5,3)& (5,4)& (5,5)& (5,6)\\
(6,1)& (6,2)& (6,3)& (6,4)& (6,5)& (6,6)
\end{array}

There are $36$ possibilities, and the sum is constant along diagonals going from bottom-left to top-right. We see that the $(5,1)-(1,5)$ diagonal is the first with sum equal to $6,$ and there are $26$ possible pairs that are on or below this diagonal. Therefore the probability is equal to $$\frac{26}{36}=\frac{13}{18}.$$